# How can you maintain the order of an array but not have terraform replace when a new item is added

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a terraform module that accepts an array of objects as a variable in dependency order. I used the `count` function to create a resource for each item in the array referencing the prior item, however when a new item is added in the middle, all items are destroyed and recreated.

I processed the array into a map and switch to a `for_each` to solve the recreate issue. This created a new issue in that order is not preserved in the map (as expected) and items are created out of order causing it to fail when they are not created. I tried using `depends_on` but you can only use items with constant keys for this to work.

I have made this generic as I have a few places this is used in different providers. The main one is aws.

```
Variable ex:
  groups = {
    "corp" = [
      {
        name = "test"
        foo = []
        bar = 124
      },
      {
        name = "test2"
        foo = ["bar"]
        bar = 567
      }
    ]
  }

variable "groups" {
  type = map(list(object({
    name = string,
    foo = list(string)
    bar = number
  }))
}

locals {
  items = flatten([
    for group_key, group_value in var.groups : [
      for i, item_value in groups_value : {
        group_name = group_key
        name     = "${group_key}-${item_value.name}"
        item     = item_value
        dep      = i == 0 ? null : "${group_key}-${var.groups[group_key][(i - 1)].name}"
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "group" "this" {
  for_each = { for r in local.items : r.name => r }

  group = each.value.group_name
  name = each.value.name
  dep = each.value.dep

  depends_on = [
    group.this["${each.value.dep}"]
  ]
}

resource "group" "this" {
  count = local.items
  group = local.items[${count.index}].group_name
  name = local.items[${count.index}].name
  dep = local.items[${count.index}].dep
}
```

Comment: Well, you can't do that. You have to re-think your architecture. TF aims to execute everything in parallel, and if you have to relay on order of items in a loop, then you end up with your issues.

Comment: I get a feeling that all you need to do is set your parallelism to 1: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/apply#parallelism-n

Comment: If you absolutely require ordering, then you must use the `list` type.

Comment: I'd note that _even when you use `count`_ the order of operations for instances of a single `resource` block is undefined. Dependencies in Terraform are between whole `resource` blocks, not between individual instances of the same resource.

Comment: `count` vs. `for_each` only changes what addresses Terraform will use to keep track of your individual instances, and has no impact on what order actions will be taken. If possible, Terraform will act on them all concurrently.

Comment: The only way I see is to call the module itself multiple times once per group and have the `module group1`  depend on `module group0` explicitly via `depends_on = [module.group0] ` (tf v0.13+) or implicitly by referencing an output value from `module group0` in the `module.group1` resources or input parameters.